# android application crashes after receiving 1 or 2 messages

Tags: java, arrays, android-studio, sockets

I am trying to communicate Client socket of Android with Server Socket in C#, i am using byte array to send and receive messages. First of all length of message is sent through byte array and then actual message through byte array, similarly at the receiving end.

But my application crashes after receiving 1 or 2 messages by showing exception "Failed to allocate a 1936942432 byte allocation with 1678239 free bytes and 510MB until OOM, target footprint 3356479, growth limit 536870912" even though I am freeing bytes after receiving the data. what is the issue ? How can I overcome this issue ?

**Here is my receiving code:**

```
              DataInputStream dist;
              final InputStream in = s.getInputStream();
              dist = new DataInputStream(in);
              final byte[] readMsgLen = new byte[4];
              dist .read(readMsgLen,0,4);
              final int length = byteArrayToInt(readMsgLen); 
              // byteArrayToInt is a function that converts byte array to int
              data = new byte[length];
              mn.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                  public void run() {
                      Toast.makeText(mn, "Message Length : "+length , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                   }
              });
              dist.readFully(data,0,data.length);
              final String msg =new String(data);
              if(msg.compareTo("Executed Successfully!") == 0){
                  mn.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                       public void run() {
                          Toast.makeText(mn, "Message: "+msg , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                          Arrays.fill(readMsgLen,(byte)0);
                          Arrays.fill(data,(byte)0);
                      }
                  });
              }
              else {
                 Intent i = new Intent(mn, imageViewer.class);
                 i.putExtra("Data", msg);
                 Arrays.fill(readMsgLen,(byte)0);
                 Arrays.fill(data,(byte)0);
                 mn.startActivity(i);
              }
```

Comment: Check your `length` variable. Has the length been properly received and decoded? `1936942432` is nearly 2GB of memory. Did you try a message that large? If we take that number and assume that it is text it would translate to "sse`". Do you recognice that sequence? It could be backwards.

Comment: I am just trying to send String, 1st time it shows length less than **500** and shows the message and next it does not give any response on every run and application crashes after trying 2 or 3 times by giving this Exception. My message is not bigger as it showing

Comment: "I am just trying to send String" Do you mean that you are just trying to send the string `String`? 6 characters long? If so, a length of 500 would be *way* to much. To me it sounds as if the fetching of the message length is out of sync somehow. Also note that the server might send the length in Little Endian format and your client might take it as Big Endian, or vise versa.

Comment: aaaarggh! You have a `DataInputStream` so use it's well-crafted methods. To get the length, just do `final int length = dist.readInt();` and get rid of all that `readMsgLen` business. Get rid of `byteArrayToInt` which, for all we know, is the source of your bugs.

Comment: Also, for any protocol issue it's not always possible to debug with just the code from one side of the protocol. The other side might be the buggy side.